# "Inverse" Riemann-Hurwitz

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, covering-spaces

I was looking through Fomenko's and Fuchs's beautifully illustrated book *Homotopical Topology* and saw the "illustration" of the $2$-fold covering between the Torus and the Klein Bottle (at page $89$ of the second edition).

Now I see that since $χ(\mathbb{T})=0=2\cdot χ(\text{Klein Bottle})$ so it doesn't violate the Riemann-Hurwitz formula.

I was wondering if the converse is true meaning if we have $2$ compact surfaces $M,N$ with $\frac{χ(M)}{χ(N)}=p \in \mathbb{N}$ can we construct a $p$-fold covering from $M$ to $N$? In particular does there exist an "arbitrary"-covering from the Torus to the Klein Bottle

Comment: The answer is yes (assuming $M,N$ are orientable). This can be done via a direct pictorial argument, I leave it for someone with skills of drawing pictures. Bassically you can embed $M$ in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ in a way $\mathbb{Z_{p}}$ acting by rotations induces the required covering.

Comment: Basically consider a rotationally symmetric torus, and do a connect sum with a surface of Euler characteristic $\chi(N)$ for each angle $2\pi i/p$, where $i = 0,1,...,p-1$. Then (if we do the connect sums appropriately) we get surface with Euler characteristic $\chi(M)$ on which $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ acts freely, so in particular induces a cover.  That is very sketchy, but it becomes very clear once you draw the correct picture. I would not be surprised if this is in some text book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: if $M$ is orientable and $N$ is not orientable (in particular, for the torus and the Klein bottle), then any covering $f:M\to N$ has even degree.  Indeed, $N$ has an "orientation double cover" $\tilde{N}\to N$ (when $N$ is the Klein bottle this is just the 2-fold covering from the torus), and $f$ must be the composition of a covering map $M\to\tilde{N}$ with this double cover.  If $N$ is orientable and $M$ is not orientable, then there are no covering maps $N\to M$ at all (any cover of an orientable manifold is orientable).

However, if $M$ and $N$ are closed connected orientable surfaces and $\chi(M)=p\chi(N)$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, then there exists a $p$-fold cover $M\to N$.  When $M$ is orientable and $N$ is not, you can then apply this with the orientation double cover $\tilde{N}$ in place of $N$ to conclude that such a cover exists as long as $p$ is even (since $\chi(\tilde{N})=2\chi(N)$).

Here's a sketch of the proof.  Let $N$ have genus $g$.  If $g=0$, then $M$ must also have genus $0$, we must have $p=1$, and we can take our cover to be a homeomorphism.  So suppose $g>0$, so $N$ is a connected sum of $g$ tori.  Then $\chi(M)=p\chi(N)$ means $M$ has genus $p(g-1)+1$.  Let us think of $N$ as one torus with $g-1$ tori attached to it, evenly spaced going around the first torus.  Similarly, $M$ is one torus with $p(g-1)$ attached to it going around.  We then get a $p$-fold cover $M\to N$ by just modding out the action of rotation by $2\pi/p$ on this picture (so every $(g-1)$st attached torus on $M$ becomes the same attached torus on $N$).  Here is a picture of this in the case $g=2$ and $p=5$, taken from [this nice answer to a similar question by Michael Albanese](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2403028/39599):

[image]

In the case $g=1$ (so $M$ and $N$ are just a torus), we can write this very explicitly.  Thinking of $M=N=S^1\times S^1$ and $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ as the set of unit complex numbers, our map $f:S^1\times S^1\to S^1\times S^1$ is just $f(z,w)=(z^p,w)$.  So, to get a covering of any even degree from the torus to the Klein bottle, you first use a map like this from the torus to itself, and then compose with the double cover from the torus to the Klein bottle.

I am not completely sure what you can say when $M$ and $N$ are both non-orientable.  I believe that if $p$ is odd, you can do a construction similar to that above, except that instead of a torus in the middle of $M$ and $N$ you have a Klein bottle.  I'm not sure you can get an even-degree cover between two non-orientable surfaces, though; this construction seems to need $p$ to be odd to be sure that the map on the Klein bottle in the middle is well-defined.

Comment: +1 Does any one have a picture (or a reference to it in a text book) of the geometric argument used for the orientable case? I would like to have one for future reference.  I cannot find anything on google images.

Comment: @NickL: Is the picture [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2403028/39599) what you're looking for? Also, see Example 1.41 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks!

Comment: That's a great picture!  I've added it to my answer.

Comment: "$\chi(M) = p\chi(N)$ means $N$ has genus $p(g-1)$" I think not...

Comment: Oops, I swapped $M$ and $N$ in that paragraph.  I've fixed it now.